# How to apply CORBA Notification Service?

Tags: c++, notifications, corba

I am ordered to apply CORBA Notification Service. I googled a lot. But all of the information is just introduction. It isn't helpful to apply this technique to a actual project.
Is there anyone can help me? Where can I start? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should explain what you want you need the Notification Service for and why you are having problems to apply it to that problem.

Comment: Please also provide the ORB (product) you have to use, as it helps us a lot to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the examples and tests that are shipped with your notication service implementation. The one as part of TAO has a lot of examples and tests that provide a good starting point. Also check the OMG Notification service specification that is available from the OMG website at www.omg.org